# Ruby Enumerable and Yield usage

Tags: ruby, shoes, enumerator

Sorry in advance if I am not asking my question in the correct way.

Trying to get this bit of Ruby code to work. What I don't understand is how to make the click do at the bottom call the yield functions (it's a traffic light) so that a click will cycle through the yield options. The true, false, false will mean the light is red because it's on at the top and the 2 bottom ones are false. I'm also having a hard time wrapping my head around enumerator and yield.

```
class TrafficLight  
  include Enumerable
  include TL

  def each
    yield [true, false, false]
    yield [true, true, false]
    yield [false, false, true] 
    yield [false, true, false] 
  end
end

class Bulb < Shoes::Shape
  attr_accessor :stack
  attr_accessor :left
  attr_accessor :top
  attr_accessor :switched_on

  def initialize(stack, left, top, switched_on = false)    
    self.stack = stack #don't change. 
    self.left = left    
    self.top = top
    self.switched_on = switched_on
    draw left, top, bulb_colour

  end

  # HINT: Shouldn't need to change this method
  def draw(left, top, colour
    )    
    stack.app do
      fill colour

      stack.append do
        oval left, top, 50
      end
    end
  end

  def bulb_colour 
    "#999999"
  end  
end

class GoBulb < Bulb
  def bulb_colour
    "#00FF30"
  end
end

class WaitBulb < Bulb
  def bulb_colour
    "#FFFC00"
  end
end

class StopBulb < Bulb
  def bulb_colour
    "#FF0000"
  end
end

module TL 
  Go = "#00FF30"
  Wait = "#FFFC00"
  Stop = "#FF0000"
end

Shoes.app :title => "My Amazing Traffic Light", :width => 150, :height => 250 do
  background "000", :curve => 10, :margin => 25  
  stroke black    

  @traffic_light = TrafficLight.new
  @top = StopBulb.new self, 50, 40, true     
  @middle = Bulb.new self, 50, 100, true
  @bottom = Bulb.new self, 50, 160, true


  click do #make this switch on/off depending on what you click. Only 1 should be on 

  end
end
```

I've Googled and searched but the enumerator examples I got didn't allow me to do what I needed to do. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to loop the enumerator (that is, should it go back to red after yellow)?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think your question could be phrased better. Try to make it really clear what your question is.  Also, you have copy/pasted quite a lot of code.  People will be more likely to take the time to read it if you reduce it to only the lines which are really needed for the question to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby (1.9.1) packed with current version of Shoes has some unexpected behavior on `Enumerator#next`. It gets stuck when this method is called. So you cannot iteratively retrieve values from an `Enumerator`.

The `TrafficLight` class has to be rewrited to mimic the `Enumerator#next`. If there isn't such bug on `next`, we can use `TraficLight.new.cycle` and repeatedly call `next on this cycling enumerator.

```rb
module TL 
  Go = "#00FF30"
  Wait = "#FFFC00"
  Stop = "#FF0000"
end

class TrafficLight
  include TL
  STATUS = [
    [true, false, false], 
    [true, true, false], 
    [false, false, true],
    [false, true, false]
  ]
  def initialize; @index = 0; end
  def current
    STATUS[@index % STATUS.size]
  end
  def next
    @index += 1
    current
  end
end
```

Update `Bulb`, add a method `update(on)` to redraw the bulb.

```rb
def update(on = false)
  self.switched_on = on
  draw self.left, self.top, on ? self.bulb_colour : '#999999'
end
```

And update the main logic of `Shoes.app` to use specific bulb:

```rb
@traffic_light = TrafficLight.new
@top = StopBulb.new self, 50, 40, true     
@middle = WaitBulb.new self, 50, 100, false
@bottom = GoBulb.new self, 50, 160, false

click do #make this switch on/off depending on what you click. Only 1 should be on 
  status = @traffic_light.next
  [@top, @middle, @bottom].zip(status).each do |light, on|
    light.update(on)
  end
end
```